# Prolonging Unity Splash screen (Android)

Tags: c#, screen, unity-game-engine, splash-screen

I'm making a little game in Unity 5.3 and i want the splash screen to last longer. Is there a way to do this without adding a second scene with the splash screen image?

Comment: I don't think you can. What's wrong with the first scene being a splash screen?

Comment: Just trying to keep it as smal as possible. But i ende up using the first scene as a splash screen and calling invoke("changeScene",2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think it is possible to customize the length of the splash screen display, but some options exist for it. Take a look at these links and you can see what is possible to customize.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileCustomizeSplashScreen.html

Comment: @Jørgen Andersen please remember to tick an answer if it was useful. Did you find any way to do it?

Comment: No, i had to add an image to the first scene and just showing that scene a couple of seconds longer.

Comment: Ah ok, that is what I suspected your options would be.